# How do you reference an assembly in web.config when it is built at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, .net-3.5

I have a WCF service that I need a custom SSL validator for client certificates. However when I attempt to tell my service what class to use I get a `TypeLoadException` saying :

> Could not load type 'ConnectorExtras.Validator' from assembly 'ConnectorExtras'.

Here is the section of Web.Config that references that class.

```
 <serviceCredentials>
    <clientCertificate>
      <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom" 
                      customCertificateValidatorType="ConnectorExtras.Validator, ConnectorExtras" />
    </clientCertificate>
  </serviceCredentials>
```

I know that section is the problem because if I leave out the assembly name `, ConnectorExtras` in the config file the error changes to

> Could not load type 'ConnectorExtras.Validator' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Here is my class for Validator. The code is sitting in `~\App_Code\Validator.cs` on the website.

```
using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using ConnectorExtras.App_GlobalResources;

namespace ConnectorExtras
{
    public class Validator : X509CertificateValidator
    {
        public Validator()
        {
            _certToCompare = new X509Certificate(ValidatorResources.TestCert, "a");
        }

        private readonly X509Certificate _certToCompare;

        public override void Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
        {
            if(certificate.Equals(_certToCompare) == false)
                throw new SecurityTokenValidationException();
        }
    }
}
```

However if I put a break point in the constructor it is never hit.

What do I need to do to use my validator to do custom certificate validation?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem. I got the same error message and in my case I had to rebuild the website in visual studio. (Build => Rebuild Website). My best guess is that the class isn't yet compiled which causes IIS to think that there is no such class.